# Setting email headers with perl

Tags: perl, email, sendmail, email-headers

I'm trying to set some email headers when sending email in perl.  I have the following code, however the Content-Type and X-Priority get sent in the body of the message.  The following is my code.

```
my $sendmail = "| /usr/sbin/sendmail -t";

open(MAIL,$sendmail)
        or die("Unable to open sendmail.  $!");
print MAIL "Reply-to: $reply\n";
print MAIL "From: $from\n";
print MAIL "To: $to\n";
print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";
print MAIL "Content-Type: text/plain\n";
print MAIL "X-Priority: 1\n";
print MAIL "blah\n";
print MAIL "$link\n\n";
close(MAIL);
```

I'm using sendmail as I'd like something out of the box without having to bother to install anything additional.

Comment: look around for already installed mail modules `perl -MFile::Find=find -MFile::Spec::Functions -le 'find{ wanted => sub{ print canonpath $_ if /\.pm\z/&&/mail/i }, no_chdir => 1 }, @INC'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove second "\n" from the line below. Sendmail treat **first** empty line as "end of headers".

print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";

### Additional fixes:

- add `-i` command line options to avoid special treatment of lines starting with dot
- specify recipients as command line arguments passed to sendmail after `--` command line option
- check sendmail exit code as returned by `close`
- use single print with "here document"

---

```
print MAIL <<"END_OF_MESSAGE";
Reply-to: $reply
From: $from
To: $to
Subject: $subject
X-Priority: 1

blah blah blah
$link
END_OF_MESSAGE
```

Comment: Thanks.  I saw that after looking at it again.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual error is that you put `\n\n` after the subject. That ends the header and starts the body.

You really should use [Net::SMTP](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/SMTP.html) which comes with almost all Perl distributions. This way, you're not dependent upon the behavior of `sendmail`.

The `Net::SMTP` module is fairly simple to use too. A lot of people don't like it because it's a bit too close to the raw protocol. A lot of people prefer something like [Mail::Sendmail](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail%3a%3aSendmail), but that's not part of Perl's standard distribution.