# Mail::Sendmail uses numeric character references and html tags even in plain text

Tags: perl, sendmail

I'm using perl's Mail::Sendmail to send email notifications, but I'm having trouble displaying Japanese. Mail::Sendmail changes the Japanese to html numeric character references, but one email client I use (claws mail) doesn't display those in html mode, while none do in text mode. Mail::Sendmail also changes newlines to `<br>`. I want neither. What am I doing wrong? I use basic options, like these for plain text:

```
            my %mail = (smtp    => 'localhost:25',
                     to      => $to,
                     from    => $from,
                     'content-type' => 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
                     subject => $subject,
                     message => $text);

            sendmail(%mail) or warn $Mail::Sendmail::error;
```

output is like:

```
            ....
            Subject: test
            Date: Fri, 19 Dec 2014 14:59:31 +0100
            Mime-Version: 1.0
            Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
            To: me@foo.com
            Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
            From: info@foo.com
            ....

            content: test this: &#x6016;&#x3044; <br>end test.=20
```

I would like to get rid of the numeric character references and html, how do I do that?

Comment: What about `$mailcfg{mime} = 0;`?

Comment: I may be way off the mark but do they go through a MS Exchange server? I've noticed in such cases the server takes liberties with the body.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera I noticed that option, but failed to understand how disabling mime would help. I'll try it now anyway.

Comment: @Recc sent from my regular client (which as similar headers) it doesn't happen, but I could try send to another server...

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera I just edited Sendmail.pm ` 'mime'    => 0,` but no difference as yet...

Comment: @Recc looks the same sent to a different server...

Comment: You shouldn't edit Sendmail.pm at all. You need to import the hash to your namespace and modify there (`use Mail::Sendmail qw(sendmail %mailcfg);$mailcfg{mime} = 0;`)

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera yeah, I saw that but also saw mentioned that one could edit Sendmail.pm, seemed quicker. Thanks for being alert!

Comment: For now I dropped Mail::Sendmail and use a more direct approach (a bit like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797433/setting-email-headers-with-perl?rq=1)). That works just fine.

Comment: After more debugging I found that the entities were added elsewhere. I'm sorry to have wasted peoples time. BTW the reason that claws mail at this time not always displays Japanese in hmtl context turns out to be that when the font in the html is undefined, claws uses a default font that doesn't display Japanese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: The assumption that Mail::Sendmail was adding the entities was *wrong*. I should have checked the other code of the program I was working on more thoroughly.